# Error in Xamarin Visual Studio While Creating A New App

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-studio

I am trying to create a new App in Xamarin Visual Studio. I have already install Visual Studio 2017 & later Xamarin package. Now while creating a cross platform app I am getting below three popup error messagg

First One

```
The 'XamarinShellPackage' package did not load correctly.The problem may have been caused by a configuration change or by the installation of another extension. You can get more information by examining the file 'C:\Users\TestNameHere\AppData\TestName\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_5c236eb4\ActivityLog.xml'.
        Restarting Visual Studio could help resolve this issue
```

.

Second

```
A problem was encountered creating the sub project 'App4.Droid'. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

and last one

```
A problem was encountered creating the sub project 'App4.iOS'. The project file 'c:\users\nic\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\App4\App4.iOS\App4.iOS.csproj' cannot be opened.

There is a missing project subtype.
Subtype: '{FEACFBD2-3405-455C-9665-78FE426C6842}' is unsupported by this installation.
```

Can anyone please suggest what am I doing wrong in installation process?

Comment: did you install android and iOS SDK's?

Comment: Yes, I have install Android SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Troubleshooting installation might help in your case [thorough uninstall for Xamarin for Visual Studio](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/windows/visual-studio/troubleshooting/uninstall-xamarinvs/)